# How to determine the number of the rows returned by slice_sample()

Tags: generics

Is there any way to know the number of the individual rows returned by slice_sample() from a data frame? I am NOT asking for the total number but the number of rows picked up at random. I would appreciate your help.
RAMT

I have tried several things but always get the total number.

Answer (score 0):

you can use len(slice_sample()) to get the number of rows.

Comment: Erika: thanks for your answer. I am more interested in know the individual rows that are retrieved not the total number. For instance, the 50th, the 100th and so on.